# cv2.findcontours() detects the Image Borders as a contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My Code should scan an image and find all contours. Within these Contours i only want the outer ones of any objekt to be displayed and marked. But by detecting the borders of my Image, it is not only ugly because of the "marked image borders", but also inaccurate, since any contour which is seen as a child contour to that border contour, will not be displayed. in my test image of an iphone, there is no outer contour of the iphone shown because of that. only the screen is detected since it is not a child contour of the image borders like the outer countour of the iphone.

I was Hoping there is a simple fix that i dont know about... If not and i did something fundamentally wrong, I will be even more happy for an answear! since... well i did something fundamentally wrong :)

here is my Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX 

bild = cv2.imread('iphone.jpg',0) 
returnSchwellWert, binäresBild = cv2.threshold(bild, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
konturen, hierachy = cv2.findContours(binäresBild, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i, aktuelleKontur in enumerate(konturen): 
    if hierachy[0][i][3] == -1:
      k = 0 
      arrayXY = [0] * len(konturen[i]) 
      for spalte in np.squeeze(konturen[i]): 
        arrayXY[k] = spalte[0] 
        k = k+1 
      arrayXY = sorted(arrayXY) 
      xLength = arrayXY[len(konturen[i])-1]-arrayXY[0] 

      k = 0 
      arrayXY = [0] * len(konturen[i]) 
      for spalte in np.squeeze(konturen[i]): 
        arrayXY[k] = spalte[1] 
        k = k+1 
      arrayXY = sorted(arrayXY) 
      yHight = arrayXY[len(konturen[i])-1]-arrayXY[0] 
    
      n = aktuelleKontur.ravel() 
      i=0
      for j in n : 
          if(i % 2 == 0): 
              x = n[i] 
              y = n[i + 1] 
  
              string = str(x) + " " + str(y)  
            
              offsetXforText = 32
              offsetYforText = 10 
              offsetforText = 20  
              if(i == 0):   
                  cv2.putText(bild, "Laenge: ", (x - offsetXforText, y + offsetYforText - offsetforText), 
                                font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0))  
                  cv2.putText(bild, str(xLength), (x + offsetXforText, y + offsetYforText - offsetforText), 
                                font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0))  
                  cv2.putText(bild, "Hoehe: ", (x - offsetXforText, y - offsetYforText - offsetforText), 
                                font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0))  
                  cv2.putText(bild, str(yHight), (x + offsetXforText, y - offsetYforText - offsetforText), 
                                font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0))   
          i += 1
      cv2.drawContours(bild, [aktuelleKontur], 0, (0, 0, 255), 1)  

cv2.imshow("Bild mit markierten Konturen", bild) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To solve my problem, i was playing arround with adding borders to padd the Image. I searched for some documentation afterwards but couldn´t find anything.

edit: i shortend the code for better understanding, but i am not able to upload any pictures. Thanks!

Comment: We cannot see your images.

Comment: At the top level, `findContours` looks for white objects on black background. If the background is white, then it gets detected as the top-level contour. Invert your threshold operation if that's the case. | To add borders, use `copyMakeBorders`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Answer: findContours does use black as a background. Therefore the Image borders are a contour to that function, it works properly even though it doesnt look like it. If you want to prevent the detection of the Borders, you have to invert the picture.
The easiest way to do so is to use cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV instead of cv2.THRESH_BINARY in the function cv2.threshold()